# Recursive IEnumerable doesn't work as expected?

Tags: c#, recursion, ienumerable

I've written a recursive function which yields `IEnumerable<int>`

```
IEnumerable<int>   Go(int b  )
{
 if (b==0) yield  return 0;
   else
 foreach (var element in Go(b-1))
  {
    yield return element;
  }
}
```

So If I write

```
foreach (var element in Go(3))
{
    Console.WriteLine (element);
}
```

It should yield

```
0
1
2
3
```

But it doesn't work as expected.  ( it displays 0).

In normal recursive function ( which return int -  without Ienumerable) it works fine.

**Question:**

How can I fix the code so it yields the expected value ?

nb. No there's no reason for using recursive Ienumerables. It's just came to my mind after playing with recursive yields.

Comment: if it should simple `0 1 2 3` why you need recursion?

Comment: as an aside, recursive yields cause a lot of non-apparent memory/cpu chum and as a new state machine is constructed every time you enter the method.

Comment: @Grundy Because I played a bit with recursive yields and didn't see the expected results so I want to go deeper.

Comment: @Grundy obviously he is not trying to create a function to print sequential integers and this is a simplified example to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another variant with condition `b==0`

```
static IEnumerable<int> Go(int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        yield return 0; //return 0 if b==0;
        yield break; // say that iteration end;
    }

    foreach (var el in Go(b - 1)) 
    {
        yield return el;
    }

    yield return b; //return current b as element of result collection

}
```

or without `yield break`

```
static IEnumerable<int> Go(int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        yield return 0;
    }
    else
    {

        foreach (var el in Go(b - 1)) 
        {
            yield return el;
        }

        yield return b; //return current b as element of result collection
    }
}
```

Comment: Though not highest rank , but it's the only answer which analogs to a regular recursive function with normal intuition of break condition. ( and of course i forgot about yield break). It was important for me to correct the way by small angles and not change completely the way. ( of course I've learned from other answers as well , but again....)

Answer (score 11):

Because you never yield b itself but only yield 0.

```
IEnumerable<int> Go(int b)
{
    if(b > 0) {
         foreach (var element in Go(b-1))
            yield return element;
    }
    yield return b;
}
```

Note that if you want the resulting sequence to start from 0 and go upwards you have to `yield return b` *after* the `foreach`. Let's unroll the first call for `Go(3)`:

```
Go(3):
foreach(var element in Go(2)):
    yield return element;
yield return 3;
```

So 3 will be the last item in the sequence (because all the others are yieled before it). Let's now unroll `Go(2)`:

```
Go(3):
    Go(2):
    foreach(var element in Go(1)):
        yield return element;
    yield return 2;
yield return 3;
```

`Go(1)`:

```
Go(3):
    Go(2):
        Go(1):
            foreach(var element in Go(0))
                yield return element;
        yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
yield return 3;
```

As you can see, result are chained "backwards" with respect to the calls:

```
Go(3) --> Go(2) --> Go(1) --> Go(0) --> 0 --> 1 --> 2 --> 3
```

Comment: what is different `yield return b;` and `yield return 0;`?

Comment: yield return b returns b every time, yield return 0 only returns 0.

Comment: @BlackBear It took me 2 minutes to comprehend your sentence :-) Do an example with one or two elements :-)

Comment: @xanatos I did with 3 just to be sure ;)

Comment: The big change here that is hard to notice is that this solution does not have an else block, it will return b if it is equal to zero, and also if it is not!

Answer (score 6):

I doubt that it would work anything different - because the only concrete `yield` I see is `yield 0`

I guess you want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> Go(int b)
{
   if (b > 0)
   {
      foreach (var element in Go(b-1))
      {
        yield return element;
      }
   }
   yield return b;
}
```

but still this is highly inefficient and will blow the stack with bigger `b`s

---

For your question:

Your code:

will do this:

```
b=3:
  is b == 0? no ok, then enumerate and return everything from b=2...
     b=2:
       is b == 0? no ok, then enumerate and return everything from b=1...
         b=1:
           is b == 0? no ok, then enumerate everything from b=0...
             b=0:
               is b == 0? **YES** so yield a single **0**
           everything was {0}
       everything was {0}
  everything was {0}
return is {0}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with checking `if(b==0)`

Answer (score 2):

Why your code doesn't work... Let's start from the end... You want [0, 1, 2, 3]. Clearly to obtain that sequence, there must be a

```
yield return 0
yield return 1
yield return 2
yield return 3
```

But in your code you can:

```
yield return 0
```

or

```
yield return the Go function
```

nowhere you have some code that can yield return the non-zero value!

Note in fact that correct code has a

```
yield return b
```

where b is the value passed to the function `Go(int b)`, so that the function will first call itself recursively to return the valeus 0...b-1 and then yield the b value.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have an IEnumerable called enumerable. If you write

```
foreach(var element in enumerable) yield return element;
```

is exactly the same as if you write

```
return enumerable;
```

if you look at the result and the return type. If you try

```
if(b == 0) yield return 0;
else return Go(b - 1);
```

It gives a compiler error: "Iterator cannot contain return statement", because if you write a function with a yield return statement in it, it won't compile to a function but an iterator, so it does not really "return". Let's modify it to get the same behavior, but with a "real function" for clarity. To make it compile, you could modify it to

```
if (b == 0) return Enumerable.Repeat(0, 1); // or return Enumerable.Range(0, 1);
else return Go(b - 1);
```

but it doesn't really make it more clear: What you did up there was almost like:

```
return b == 0 ? 0 : Go(b-1);
```

but the result is wrapped in an IEnumerable. I hope it's clear now why it returns only one 0.

Answer (score 1):

Adding visualization : ( just to show flow if yields) method name according to the `b` param

took me a while  to see what's going on here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is flawed. :-)

What it does is that the Go method only ever yields the value 0. If called with 3, then it gets down to the last recursive call whicht returns 0. The foreach iterates just that one 0 and yields it again. SO the zero is yielded on every level as the only element.